# How to reshare articles using association with the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called article with columns : `id, title, content, user_id`, i want to use association with the same table to say that article can be reshared by other users, so when a user reshare an article i think this is not necessary to copy the whole row of the origianl article, but just copy a reference to it , but how to do this using active record ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the user_id from table articles, add a new association table call user_articles,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_articles
  has_many :articles, :through => :user_articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_articles
  has_many :user, :through => :user_articles
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end
```